# js. get multiple values using id

Tags: javascript, html, selector

```
function handleUser(activeMenu, user) {
$('#accordion').html("");
  $.each(user, (index, user) => {
    $('#accordion').append(
<input class="control" id="a${user.userId}" value=${user.name}></input>
<input class="control" id="b${user.userId}" value=${user.email}></input>
<input class="control" id="c${user.userId}" value=${user.phone}></input> 
<input class="control" id="d${user.userId}" value=${user.address}></input>
<button class="info-actions" id="${user.userId}">
    save
</button>)});}
```

^ this code above here pulls data from the db fine.

However, to save.... I need to get each values.

```
function handleInfo() {
    $('#accordion').on('click','.info-actions',(event) => {
        let target = $(event.target).attr('id');
        console.log(target);
//this prints the id fine.

//let x = $('.control').attr('value');
//let x = $(`#a${target}`);
//let x = $(`#a${target}`);
//let x = $('#a${target}').val();
        console.log(x);

//..... then going to use ajax to connect controller.(Which I can handle)
})}
```

I've tried many ways...
Not sure how to get values for each ids using the target.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: //let x = $('.control').attr('value');
//let x = $(`#a${target}`);
//let x = $(`#a${target}`);
//let x = $('#a${target}').val();

Comment: instead of targeting by id you can query them by their tagname ... something like `$(this).children('input').forEach()`

Comment: $(this)   <-- is referring to?   Multiple users have their name, email, phone, and address. I'm setting id to a${user.userId} so each users will have different input id for their name, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it had some issues with the ids having spaces/, etc. between them or something.

I've found a work-around to solve the issue.

Just used:

```
var name = "a" + target;
var nameVal = document.getElementById(name).value;
```

and etc.